# How can i add a feature that the user can decide how many passwords he wants?

Tags: php, html, regex

I made a password generator for my company and now I want to add the feature that the user can decide how many passwords he wants.

I tried `str_repeat ($output , $password_amount )` but then I get the same password twice and my output field looks like this when I want 2 passwords e.g. 123abc123abc.

I'm a beginner. I am open for any improvements and guidance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang=de>
<head>
<title>Passwort Generator/Tester | </title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"charset="utf-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="PasswortStyle.css" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="Logo.ico"/>
<img class="logo" src="logo.png" alt="Logo"/>



<script>
  function myFunction() {

  var copyText = document.getElementById("password");

  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);

  document.execCommand("copy");
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<h1 id="firstHeading">Passwort-Generator</h1>
<div class="passwordgen">

<?php
    $numbs = array("0","1","2",
    "3","4","5","6","7","8","9","@","!","$",
    "%","&","?",",",".","-",":","_","#","+","*","q","w","e",
    "r","t","z","u","i","o","p","a","s",
    "d","f","g","h","j","k","l","y","x","c","v","b","n","m","Q","W","E",
    "R","T","Z","U","I","O","P","A","S",
    "D","F","G","H","J","K","L","Y","X","C","V","B","N","M");
    shuffle($numbs);

    $password_amount = 1;
    if (isset ($_POST['amount']) ) $password_amount = ($_POST['amount']) ;

    $password_length = 10;
    if (isset ($_POST['lenght']) ) $password_length = ($_POST['lenght']) ;
    $output = "";

    for($i=0;$i<$password_length;$i++){
    $output .= $numbs[array_rand($numbs)];
}



if (!preg_match('/^((?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?\d)|(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[^a-zA-Z0-9])|(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[^a-zA-Z0-9])|(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[^a-zA-Z0-9])).{8,}$/', $output)){   #  (1,2,3|1,2,4|1,3,4|2,3,4) 4 mögliche Kombinationen
    $message = "<span style=\"color:red\">Das Passwort entspricht nicht den <a style=\"color:red; text-decoration:underline;\" href=\"http://Passwortrichtlinien\">SKOPOS-Richtlinien</a></span>";
    } else{
    $message = "<span style=\"color:green\">Das Passwort entspricht den <a style=\"color:green; text-decoration:underline;\" href=\"http://Passwortrichtlinien\">SKOPOS-Richtlinien</a></span>";
    }

    $size = round($password_length * 1.2);
    echo"<center>Zufälliges Passwort:<input type = \"text\" id= \"password\" value=\"".$password."\" size=\"".$size."\" style=\"font-size:16pt; text-align:center; margin: 17px; font-family=\"Monaco, monospace;\" \" /><br/>
    ".$message."
    </center>";

  ?>
<center>
  <form method="post">
   <p>Passwortlänge: <input type="number" name="lenght" min="1" max="100" value="<?= $password_length?>"/> Anzahl an Passwörter: <input type="number" name="count" min="1" value="<?= $password_amount?>"/></p>
   <p><button class="button" type="submit">Neues Passwort</button></p>
   <p><button class="button" onclick="myFunction()">Passwort in Zwischenablage kopieren</button></p>
  </form>
</center>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "how many passwords"? Why should a user have multiple passwords?

Comment: The str_repeat() function repeats a string a specified number of times. It's normal you get the same password multiple times..

Comment: @Nico Haase For some projects with other companys we need a lot of passwords for example when we create accounts for a bunch of people or something. Then is it easier to output 10 or 100 passwords than copy only one password behind each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare your generator as a function and then call it multiple times in a loop for example.

```
function generatePassword($password_length) {  
    $numbs = array("0","1","2",
    "3","4","5","6","7","8","9","@","!","$",
    "%","&","?",",",".","-",":","_","#","+","*","q","w","e",
    "r","t","z","u","i","o","p","a","s",
    "d","f","g","h","j","k","l","y","x","c","v","b","n","m","Q","W","E",
    "R","T","Z","U","I","O","P","A","S",
    "D","F","G","H","J","K","L","Y","X","C","V","B","N","M");
    shuffle($numbs);
    $output = "";

    for($i=0;$i<$password_length;$i++){
        $output .= $numbs[array_rand($numbs)];
    }
return $output;
}
```

And call it like:

```
$passwords = [];

for($i=0;$i<=$_POST["amount"]-1;$i++) // Repeat generating desired number of times
$passwords[] = generatePassword($_POST["length"]);
var_dump($passwords); //This is the array of your passwords
```

**EDIT:** At your request, this is how you incorporate this to your code:

```
<?php
function generatePassword($password_length) { //Function to generate the password
    $numbs = array("0","1","2",
    "3","4","5","6","7","8","9","@","!","$",
    "%","&","?",",",".","-",":","_","#","+","*","q","w","e",
    "r","t","z","u","i","o","p","a","s",
    "d","f","g","h","j","k","l","y","x","c","v","b","n","m","Q","W","E",
    "R","T","Z","U","I","O","P","A","S",
    "D","F","G","H","J","K","L","Y","X","C","V","B","N","M");
    shuffle($numbs);
    $output = "";

    for($i=0;$i<$password_length;$i++){
        $output .= $numbs[array_rand($numbs)];
    }
    return $output;
}

if(isset($_POST["lenght"]) { // If user submitted a form
    for($i=0;$i<=$amount_of_passwords-1;$i++) { // Repeat generating desired number of times
        $password = generatePassword($_POST["length"]);

//Regex match on $password
if (!preg_match('/^((?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?\d)|(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?            [a-z])(?=.*?[^a-zA-Z0-9])|(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[^a-zA-Z0-9])|(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[^a-zA-Z0-9])).{8,}$/', $password)){   #  (1,2,3|1,2,4|1,3,4|2,3,4) 4 mögliche Kombinationen
$message = "<span style=\"color:red\">Das Passwort entspricht nicht den <a style=\"color:red; text-decoration:underline;\" href=\"http://Passwortrichtlinien\">SKOPOS-Richtlinien</a></span>";
} else{
$message = "<span style=\"color:green\">Das Passwort entspricht den <a style=\"color:green; text-decoration:underline;\" href=\"http://Passwortrichtlinien\">SKOPOS-Richtlinien</a></span>";
}

$size = round($_POST["lenght"] * 1.2);
echo"<center>Zufälliges Passwort:<input type = \"text\" id= \"password\" value=\"".$password."\" size=\"".$size."\" style=\"font-size:16pt; text-align:center; margin: 17px; font-family=\"Monaco, monospace;\" \" /><br/>
".$message."
</center>";
    }
}
?>
```

This will generate desired number of passwords, check if they are valid based on your regular expression and print them as you have done. You just need to replace `$amount_of_passwords` with the desired number or let user choose in form and then pass it as `$_POST["amount"]` for example.

Comment: Ok thanks i think that will solve my problem but how i include your code in my code? I tried to incude it but i dont get it.

Comment: See my last edit.